# Forwarding URLs

Tags: url, ngrok

i have a wordpress website, i would like the client to view the website but i do not want to go through all the trouble of uploading the files and database to the server online, so i looked around and found some tunneling software that worked for me.  However the issue i am now having is when the website is loaded from another PC, the **css** and **images** are not loaded because they all have their urls set to **localhost**.  I read around and saw a lot of fancy words like url forwarding changing somethings in httpd-vhosts.conf etc. Unfortunately i do not know much abbout networking to understand all these concepts.

Basically what i would like to know is is there a way to make my **images** and **css** load on the clients pc even though the urls are set to **locahost**?

Or if anyone has another way i can show a client a website from my localhost.

I tried both **pagekite** and **ngroks** thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one of the following plugins to Wordpress to force it to use relative URLs:

https://github.com/optimizamx/odt-relative-urls

http://wordpress.org/plugins/relative-url/

http://wordpress.org/plugins/root-relative-urls/

Answer (score -1):

I guess it would be far better to host your site on a free web hosting service to show your client the website you created in one piece but make sure that the service provider provides everything that your website needs.